# Fail to parse array of string using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

This code :

```
JSON.parse("['Testing avionics, electrical and mission wiring, verifying the correct installation of cabling, solving harness']")
```

Return this error :

```
VM2642:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

But this code works perfectly :

```
var arr = ['Testing avionics, electrical and mission wiring, verifying the correct installation of cabling, solving harness']
```

So is there a better way to parse than JSON? The only solution I see is to make my own parser.

I'm using google chrome v 66.0.3359.181

Comment: JSON requires double quotes, not single.

Comment: `JSON.parse('["Testing avionics, electrical and mission wiring, verifying the correct installation of cabling, solving harness"]')` will work

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) uses double quotes (`"`) to enclose the strings. Your input is not valid JSON.

Comment: *"But this code works perfectly :"* -- that code is JavaScript, not JSON. JSON is a subset of JavaScript and the strings enclosed in single quotes are JavaScript but not part of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write your own parser. In javascript double quotes json is standard json format. So you can use double quotes inside your json and wrap it in a single quote for it to be parsed as **valid JSON**.

```js
var arr = JSON.parse('["Testing avionics, electrical and mission wiring, verifying the correct installation of cabling, solving harness"]');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: sorry but it Isn't marked as duplicate

Comment: Can't change le simple quote that easily, gonna make my own parser. Not sure if I should mark my question as a duplicate, the other one is about JQuery (even if it's the same).